# How do I see a list of yarn installed dependencies?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When I install dependencies from `package.json` using `npm install`, I can see a list of all installed dependencies under the `node_modules` directory. However, the same is not true for `yarn`. When I do a `yarn`/`yarn install`, I see a `.yarn-integrity` file. How can I see a list of installed dependencies?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For Yarn 2 and onwards you can use [`yarn info --name-only`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/info).

For Yarn 1 you can use [`yarn list`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/list).

Comment: @MattR then what does?

Comment: @koolkat `yarn info --name-only`

Answer (score 11):

For Yarn 2, run:

```
yarn info --name-only
```

Answer (score 7):

The `yarn list` command is what you need. You can find the full documentation of this command here: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/list

'yarn help' can also show you what commands are available plus some additional info.